# C++ Downloading File By Curl Library Linker Error

Tags: c++, file, curl, linker, download

I'm trying to download a file a by curl library. I have downloaded the the curl library. But I get linker error when I try to compile. 
Here is the code that I used:

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/CckAcRvB)

Here is the screenshot of linker errors:
[Linker Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRs1q.png)
How can ı solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Posted 2 years ago...

Comment: What difference does it make that it was posted 2 years ago?